# startx from mac osx to RHEL6

Tags: ssh, rhel, gnome, osx

I am trying to get a GUI over ssh -X.

My RHEL6 server did not have X Window System and a graphical desktop environment. So I installed using `yum groupinstall "X Window System" Desktop`. It installed completely.

I also enabled `X11 Forwarding`.

Now I am trying to get the GUI from ssh from my Mac. 
I do `ssh -X devserver`. Then I type `sudo startx`, but it gives me this error.

```
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
Initializing built-in extension DRI2
Loading extension GLX
GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET=/tmp/keyring-2T42OF/socket
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-2T42OF/socket.ssh
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=14059

** (gnome-panel:14074): CRITICAL **: panel_key_file_load_from_uri: assertion `uri != NULL' failed

** (gnome-panel:14074): CRITICAL **: panel_key_file_load_from_uri: assertion `uri != NULL' failed

** (gnome-panel:14074): WARNING **: panel-applet-frame.c:1288: failed to load applet OAFIID:GnoteApplet:
(null)
```

**Is this the right way. If not how do I properly get a GUI of RHEL on mac?**

Answer (score 2):

Your going about this the wrong way.

First the X Server needs to be running on your mac.
Then `ssh -x devserver`
Finally run a GUI app like `gedit`.

The gedit window should show on your mac.

Remember, in this case, "X" is "hosting" for gedit, the "client". It is a different perspective then most people are used to.

The host ("X") gets instructions on what to draw from the client. Then draws them. We tend to think of a server as a remote machine, but in fact it's just the software that "accepts" connections that is the "server". In this case, X on mac is the one accepting connections (from gedit on RHEL).

Comment: There is also XDMCP but that is generally not recommended for short term connections, I will let you google that one.

Comment: Maybe you did not understand my question. I am aware of running running apps over ssh -x option. On my mac I have XQuartz running. I am trying to run gui RHEL desktop interface. Like gnome. I try to start it with startx and am given the error.

Comment: Then look into XDMCP. starx starts X, and that's not what you want.  X is already running on your mac.